# Limit/filter lucene search by an id list (IN operator)

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, lucene, hibernate-search

I would like to search for messages, e.g. based on their title, and subject.
But I have a list with ID's in which lucene may search.

I just want to add a restriction on the id's.. Seems like an easy task, but can't find a solution...
So basically: (search query) AND (id IN (list-of-ids)).

As I understand, there is no IN-operator in lucene. 
I've tried combining BooleanJunctions, but without success so far.
I've tried implementing a filter, but this expects a DocIdSet/DocIdSetIterator, which is pretty strange.

It's implemented in Java and lucene's version is 3.6.2.

Something I have tried:

```
    final FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getSession());
    final QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Message.class).get();
    final BooleanJunction<?> booleanJunction = queryBuilder.bool();

    final String[] searchTerms = StringUtils.split(criteria, "\\W+");

    for (final String term : searchTerms) {
        if (StringUtils.length(term) > 2) {
            BooleanJunction<?> booleanJunctionIds = queryBuilder.bool();
            for (Long id : messageIds) {
                booleanJunctionIds.must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("id").matching(id).createQuery());
            }
            BooleanJunction<?> booleanJunctionSearch = queryBuilder.bool();
            booleanJunctionSearch.should(queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("subject").matching(criteria).createQuery());
            /**...**/

            booleanJunction.must(booleanJunctionIds.createQuery()).must(booleanJunctionSearch.createQuery()).createQuery();
        }
    }

    final FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(booleanJunction.createQuery(), Message.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The general approach of creating a BooleanQuery with the right combination of nesting *must* and *should* elements is correct: this should work.

You might be having some issues with how "id" terms are encoded, or similarly on "subject": you are requiring these sub clauses of the BooleanQuery to use exact keyword matches, and doing the splitting of the input criteria yourself.

This is sometimes desirable but is a bit error prone, as the encoding needs to be exactly the same, including the case of each keyword: you might want to make sure that the individual clauses if the BooleanQuery do match the elements you are expecting.

I'd suggest to introduce tests for individual elements before you merge the various Lucene *Query* instances so that you can verify that any text processing is matching, and only then combine them with boolean operators.